# How to use ItemReader with current chunk context?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I'm trying to create an `ItemReader` for `spring-batch`. But the reader should be reinvoked on each `chunk`, and fetch additional data using the chunk parameter (which would result in some kind of pagination for the url):

```
private final RestTemplate tempalte = new RestTemplate();

@Bean
public ItemReader<MyDTO> getReader() {
    return tempalte.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, headers, currentChunkIndex); //TODO how to?
}
```

Configured with:

@Bean

```
public Step step() {
    return stepBuilder.get("jobname")
        .<MyDTO, MyEntity>chunk(100)
        .reader(getReader())
        .writer(getWriter())
        .build(),
}
```

Question: hwo could I achieve this: refresh the reader on each `chunk` iteration, and moreover use the chunk index itself?

Comment: The `RestTemplate.exchange(...)` method returns `<T> ResponseEntity<T>`. How do you expect to cast that to an `ItemReader`?

Comment: `ItemReader.read()` might call `RestTemplate.exchange()`.

Answer (score 0):

The Spring Batch framework will continue to call `reader.read()` until the method returns `null`. The pattern you should follow here is to have your reader implement `ItemStream` and use the `update` method to move your pagination bookmark.

During the job, you'd maintain a state variable in your reader that tracks its own progress. And in the event of a failure, your `open` method (also part of `ItemStream`) would fetch the state from the step's `ExecutionContext` to pick up where you left off. More on `ItemStream` can be found [here in the Spring Batch docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#itemStream).

Note: You could also accomplish something very close by implementing `StepExecutionListener` instead.

Comment: So it's not possible to read the current "chunk index` from Execution or Step Context? And I therefore have to keep track of it myself in my custom reader?

Comment: The `update` method from `ItemStream` has access to the step's `ExecutionContext`. Please clarify where exactly this "chunk index" is coming from. If it is the index number the last record you've read, then how do expect it to get into your context?